# How do i prevent endless loop in while loop in action creator?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, while-loop

Trying to implement some kind of game loop, that will run until conditions are met.

However during testing I just can't solve the problem of while loop not waiting for resolve of promises, instead it just calls them over and over again causuing browser to crash.

The combatStart() is called when component is mounted

```
export const combatStart = () => {
    return function (dispatch, getState) {

        while (getState().mechanics.noOfEnemiesAttacked < 5) {
            let setTimeoutPromise = new Promise(resolve => {
                let success = true;
                setTimeout(function () { resolve(success) }, 3000);
            })

            setTimeoutPromise.then((resp) => {
                if(resp){
                    dispatch({
                        type: 'INCREMENT_ENEMIES_ATTACKED'
                    })
                }

            })
       }
    }
}
```

When i dispatch the action the "noOfEnemiesAttacked" increments, and when it reaches 5 the loop should stop. So it should last around 15 seconds.

The code works until I add the while loop, otherwise it works as expected, increments the value after 3 seconds when component is mounted.

How can I make this work?

Recursively doesnt work, it doesnt loop, just goes once:

```
export const combatStart = () => {
    return function (dispatch, getState) {
        let setTimeoutPromise = new Promise(resolve => {
            let success = true;
            setTimeout(function () { resolve(success) }, 2000);
        })

        setTimeoutPromise.then((resp) => {
            if (resp) {
                dispatch({
                    type: 'INCREMENT_ENEMIES_ATTACKED'
                })
            }
            if (getState().mechanics.noOfEnemiesAttacked < 5) {
                console.log(getState().mechanics.noOfEnemiesAttacked)
                combatStart();
            }
        })

    }
}
```

Comment: Why use Promises here?  What do you gain by using them vs. not using them?

Comment: Promises resolve asynchronously. You can't wait for it in a loop, because async code doesn't run until the loop finishes.

Comment: If you want to run an async loop then you need to write it recursively.

Comment: Tried doing it recursively, it doesnt start again though, updating main post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapped it in a function, now it should work

```
export const combatStart = () => {
    return function (dispatch, getState) {
        function foo(){
            let setTimeoutPromise = new Promise(resolve => {
                let success = true;
                setTimeout(function () { resolve(success) }, 2000);
            })

            setTimeoutPromise.then((resp) => {
                if (resp) {
                    dispatch({
                        type: 'INCREMENT_ENEMIES_ATTACKED'
                    })
                }
                if (getState().mechanics.noOfEnemiesAttacked < 5) {
                    console.log(getState().mechanics.noOfEnemiesAttacked)
                    combatStart();
                    foo();
                }
            })
        }

        foo();
    }
}
```